# Check thread eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, plugins

Is there a tool I can use to see what parts of the code are in which thread (colour code it or something)? I'm mostly concerned about EDT, but writing that isOnEventDispatchThread()-ish command every other line and then keeping track of it's output while the program is running is tedious and time consuming.

Comment: The major problem I'd see with this is code that can be called from any thread, such as constructors.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem I'd see with this is code that can be called from any thread, such as constructors. You can however use Eclipse's debugger at runtime. Simply run the program in the debugger until a breakpoint or with manual pause then look at the "debug" view that is generally in the upper left. You'll see threads and may select one to jump to its location.

Comment: Maybe a different approach then... Is there a code analyser which can detect when a new thread is executed or whenever there is a point in code where it changes the thread it's executing on?

Comment: @Karlovsky120 The debugger can do that at runtime though you'd have to know which thread(s) you want to look at. Basically it tells you threads->stacks and positions, but not the reverse.

Comment: @Karlovsky120 You can execute code on different threads using reflection at run time so it compile time it is unknown what runs on which thread...